# Using IMU for a small Arduino and bluetooth support

Tags: bluetooth, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm gonna start a project with an IMU with a bluetooth support inside a small board (mini or lillypad) and send datas to the mobile phone. But I'm quite new to those kind of technologies.

I'm going to choose a module for handling both operate voltage restriction and memory capacity for both library (IMU and bluetooth).

Any advice obj which arduino / IMU breakout / bluetooth module / battery to use? Or some similar projects?

Comment: A tiny quadcopter board will have the intertial sensors and you can add a bluetooth module.  Or you can use an arduino-with-bluetooth type board and add an intertial module.  Beware that cheap micromachined IMUs (or for that matter just about any you can buy) aren't very good - they are fine for detecting or damping acceleration and rotation, but not for integrating to determine position or even velocity.

Comment: can you advice one or two good breakout board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to Arduino I'd suggest avoiding the Mini and the BULLSH-fun that external programmers bring. 
Something like the Pro Micro is much easier, almost as small, and less likely to bite.

Often the best way to pick hardware is to look for a tutorial (like [This](http://bildr.org/2012/03/stable-orientation-digital-imu-6dof-arduino/) one) before deciding what to buy. While I personally haven't used IMUs it looks like the "6 Degrees of Freedom IMU Digital Combo Board - ITG3200/ADXL345" from SparkFun would be (relatively) easy to use.

I've used the RN-41/2 Bluetooth modems (the same as are found in BlueSMiRF modules) and usually gotten on OK with them. There are plenty of tutorials available with a bit of Googleing.

[Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/categories/138) do a good line of Lipo batteries and chargers. They also have wireless charging modules if you're looking for extra brag-factor.

Hope this helps.